# Anyone have any idea why my code is not printing anything?

Tags: python

I am pretty new to programming as a whole and was trying to program a calculator in python.

```
calc_version = input("Please choose a calc type (1/2)")
if calc_version == 1:
    calc_type = input("Enter Function (Add/Sub/Div/Mult) ")
    number1 = input("Please enter the first number ")
    number2 = input("Please enter the second number ")
    if calc_type == "Add":
        Sum = float(number1) + float(number2)
    if calc_type == "Sub":
        Sum = float(number1) - float(number2)
    if calc_type == "Div":
        Sum = float(number1) / float(number2)
    if calc_type == "Mult":
        Sum = float(number1) * float(number2)
    print("The sum of" ,number1, "and" ,number2, "is" ,Sum,)
if calc_version == 2:
    number1 = input("Please enter the first number ")
    operator = ("Please choose an operator (+,-,*,/)")
    number2 = input("Please enter the second number ")
    if operator == "+":
        Sum = float(number1) + float(number2)
    if operator == "-":
        Sum = float(number1) - float(number2)
    if operator == "/":
        Sum = float(number1) / float(number2)
    if operator == "*":
        Sum = float(number1) * float(number2)
    print("The sum of" ,number1, "and" ,number2, "is" ,Sum,)
```

It was working fine until I added a second version under the first, the `calc_version = input("Please choose a calc type (1/2)"` line appears to have broken my whole code as nothing prints at all.
If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be a great help.

Comment: `print(repr(calc_version))` – what is it? Not `1` or `2`, but likely `'1'` or `'2'` (a string).

Comment: Naming differences, quotients and products `Sum` is an odd choice for a variable name. Why not e.g. `result`?

Comment: Most likely you're using python 3 (bracketed print), which input() returns str, not int. and that you're comparing str == int

Comment: `1` and `'1'` are not the same thing. One is an integer, the other is a string. `input` returns strings

Comment: This has *got* to be a duplicate of something ...

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get your code to run by converting `calc_version` to an int before comparing to an int.

So 
`if int(calc_version) == 1: ...` and `if int(calc_version) == 2: ...`

Or, you could compare calc_version to `'1'` and `'2'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your **input()** function returns by default a string, yet you are comparing two integers (1 and 2).

Because **calc_version** is compared with 1 and 2 (which is not equal), none of the if statements are true, therefore nothing is running. As others have suggested,

```
calc_version = int(input("Please choose a calc type (1/2)"))
```

should do the trick.